# Custom Bot for Sharepoint Notifications in MS Teams?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, bots, sharepoint-workflow, microsoft-teams

I have a list in Sharepoint with a column of data type `Person/Group.` I would like to create a `SP` workflow to send a **MS Teams notification** to a person when their name is entered in the column. Would a custom bot be the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you for your help with this!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid MS Teams doesn't support exactly what you're looking to do. Bots aren't allowed to initiate 1:1 conversations with users. However, as a workaround, you should be able to have the bot create new conversations in a channel and mention the associated user. See the [documentation on bots starting conversations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/botsconversation).

Note that above does not work for *Custom* bots, since those aren't allowed to initiate any conversation at all. See [custom bot limitations here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/custombot).

An [Office 365 Connector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/connectors) might be used as a more lightweight workaround solution, but I'm not sure it supports mentions.